# Black background when view rotates on orientation change

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, autolayout, screen-rotation

I am fiddling with an orientation change responsive app in Xcode and am trying to figure out how I can change that my non-black view seems to rotate on a black background on orientation change!

It looks something like this:

[image]

I would like to change the black background to the colour of my view - which is pink in the depicted case.

When my app launches it also shows a black screen until the actual view appears. I have the feeling that it is the same black that becomes visible on orientation change?

I have tried to change the background colour of the window in the did-finish-launching method of my app delegate, but that did not have any effect:

```
- (BOOL) application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {

    self.window.backgroundColor = [UIColor purpleColor];

    ...
}
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: It looks like your question could be solved in the same manner as another StackOverflow question. Check out my answer there: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10037924/can-i-rotate-a-uiview-without-the-black-bars/43896578#43896578

Answer (score 0):

Try using `willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation:duration:` method instead of `willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:duration:`

But I think nearly all of the apps in iOS show a glimpse of black background, it seems normal. In your case if it is for long time, try reducing the duration time.

Also check this [Stackoverflow Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22427096/change-color-behind-app-on-rotation)

Comment: I am not using any of the methods as things seems to happen automatically... what am I missing here? :}

Comment: If I am not wrong, you tried giving purple color to background, but its for your app's background and not for the background of the screen, which is iOS springboard.

Comment: Could you kindly elaborate on that, @Omer? :)